# Can the Google Maps API be used to determine if you are on or off a road given a GPS coordinate?

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking for a way that I can use the google maps api to determine if, given a gps coordinate, the point falls on or off of a road.

Anyone know if this is possible, or even better, how to accomplish this?

Comment: probably should add the google-maps-api-3 tag to your question

Answer (score 1):

If you use the directions service, it will return the nearest road (if it can find one).  You can measure the distance from the point it returns and your point to make a determination on whether or not they are the "same" (depends on how accurate your GPS is).

You might find the results of [this search of the Google Maps API v3](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/search?hl=en&group=google-maps-js-api-v3&q=snap+to+road&qt_g=Search+this+group) useful